# I attempted to parse a string into different words, attempted to freed them later but 2 of the strings have the same byte addresses

Tags: c, string, pointers, free

I am currently trying to parse a string into an array of strings.

So far, I currently believe I've succeeded in splitting up the string by inserting `'\0'` after every word "chunk".

However, when I attempt to free the string array later, some of my words have the same byte address, and thus, when I try to free one of them, the other gets freed as well.

This is the code for my parser, I apologize for its messy form:

```c
/*
 * parser()
 * 
 * Parses a given string into different words and returns a list with the words.
 * If there is a non-space and non-alphabetic character an error is recorded.
 */ 
void parser(char* str, char** actualList, char** freeingList,char* error, int* length){
    // initialize variables
    bool chara = false;
    bool beginning = true;
    int size = strlen(str);
    bool nonAlphaSpace = false;

    // iterate through the entire string
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        // if the character is not either a space or an alphabetic character
        if(isspace(str[i])==0 && isalpha(str[i])==0 && !nonAlphaSpace){
            *error = str[i];
            nonAlphaSpace = true;
        }
    }
    // if there was no irregular character
    if(!nonAlphaSpace){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            // if the character is the beginning of the current string
            if(beginning){
                // record this string into the list of words
                freeingList[*length] = &str[j];
                (*length)++;
                // set the status of any alphabetic character being present to false;
                chara = false;
                // if the current character is an alphabetic character
                if(isalpha(str[j])!=0){
                    chara = true;
                }
                beginning = false;
            }
            // if the character is a space
            else if(isspace(str[j])!=0){
                // if there was a character beforehand
                if(chara){
                    // get the pointer to the next character
                    char* new = &str[j+1];
                    // change the current character to a null
                    str[j] = '\0';
                    // realign the pointer to the string to rest of the string
                    str = new;
                    j = -1;
                    size = strlen(str);
                    beginning = true;
                }
            }
            // if the character is an alphabetic character
            else{
                chara = true;
            }
        }
        // if the last chunk of string left didn't contain any characters
        if(!chara){
            free(str);
        }
        // for every word extracted
        for(int k = 0; k < *length; k++){
            int newSize = strlen(freeingList[k]);
            bool first = true;
            // get the pointer to the first character in the word, i.e. not the first few spaces
            for(int l = 0; l < newSize; l++){
                if(isspace(freeingList[k][l])==0 && first){
                    actualList[k] = &freeingList[k][l];
                    first = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is when I attempt to free it:

```
// free the current collection of strings
for(int j = 0; j < size; j+=2){
    free(words[j]);
}
```

When I input `"home or for"` into the parser and later try to free it, the address of `"home"` is `0x7fffffffe840` while the address of `"for"` is `0x7fffffffe848`. This leads me to believe that the freeing of `home` also frees `or` causing a SIGABRT error later.

Is this assumption correct? How can I overcome this double freeing?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: *`isspace(str[i]) == 0 && isalpha(str[i]) == 0`* – `isalnum()` ...  – *`nonAlphaSpace = true;`* – why not just return?

Comment: I don't see where you `malloc()` anything so why do you call `free()`?

Comment: How do you allocate the thing you pass as the first argument to `parser()` in the first place?

Comment: Thank you for looking through and I apologize for the messy question format, I will try to improve in future questions. 

On the question of the returning if there is a wrong character, I did so because I wanted to return a char** type intially, so a single char* returning would've been problematic. But later when I tried t compile, the compiler warned that local variables were not wise to return, and thus I later changed the return type to `void`. 

It's very inefficient and convulted and again, I apologize for it.

Comment: I passed the string by reading a line through `stdin`.

Comment: You don't answer the question.

Comment: you neither show the code where you do `malloc(3)` nor the code where you do `free(3)` so what is this code about? What is the question about? What do you mean with freeing? Do you mean calling `free(3)` ?  what do you mean with _some of my words have the same byte address_ ???

Comment: Why do you try to solve a lot of problems in the same function, why not simply try to get the next word and then add it to the list of strings.  I don't see the need to navigate at least three times the whole string to get it's length, then  to check the valid characters, then...

Comment: Please don't use `new` as an identifier in C, because you can run into trouble if you try later to use that code in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You should only call `free()` on pointers returned by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()`. What it looks like you are doing:

```
char *ptr = malloc(100);
char *ptr2 = &ptr[10];
free(ptr2);    // You can't do that.
```

I suspect you meant to make a copy of the strings. Here's a simplified version:

```
void parser(char* str, char** actualList, int* length) {
    char *start = str;   // The start of the current string
    int count = 0;       // Number of strings copied
    while (*str) {
        if (isspace(*str)) {
            *str = '\0';
            actualList[count] = malloc(strlen(start) + 1);   // Allocate space for string
            strcpy(actualList[count++], start);   // Copy string
            start = str + 1;                          // Reset for next string
            if (count == *length - 1) break;      // Don't overflow pointer array
        }
        str++;
    }
    // Grab the final string
    actualList[count] = malloc(strlen(start) + 1);   // Allocate space for string
    strcpy(actualList[count++], start);              // Copy string

    *length = count;
}
```

Then call it like:

```
char input[] = "home or for";
char *words[5];
int max_words = 5;
parser(input, words, &max_words);
// max_words should be 3 now
for (int i = 0; i < max_words; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", words[i]);
}
// Clean up
for (int i = 0; i < max_words; i++) {
    free(words[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
home
or
for
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not a parser, though. More a tokenizer.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool parser(char const *str, char ***words, size_t *num_words, size_t *error)
{  //                             ^^^ gaaaah! *)
    assert(words);

    errno = 0;
    size_t length = strlen(str);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if (!isalnum(str[i]) && !isspace(str[i])) {
            *error = i;    // the position is most likely more meaningful than the character
            return false;  // get outta here!!
        }
    }

    char const *begin;
    char const *end;

    *num_words = 0;
    *words = NULL;

    bool in_word = false;
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= length; ++i) {
        if (!in_word && isalnum(str[i])) {  // word begins
            begin = str + i;
            in_word = true;
        }
        else if (in_word && !isalnum(str[i])) {  // word ended
            end = str + i;
            char *word = calloc(end - begin + 1, sizeof *word);
            if (!word) {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < num_words; ++i)
                    free((*words)[i]);
                free(*words);
                errno = ENOMEM;
                return false;               
            }

            memcpy(word, begin, end - begin);

            char **tmp = realloc(*words, (*num_words + 1) * sizeof *tmp);
            if (!tmp) {
                free(word);
                for (size_t i = 0; i < num_words; ++i)
                    free((*words)[i]);
                free(*words);
                errno = ENOMEM;
                return false;               
            }
            *words = tmp;
            tmp[(*num_words)++] = word;
            in_word = false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    char const *foo = "slfkja     askdfj jk j aksjf lasjdflkjsdlf jask fdjl";
    char **words = NULL;
    size_t num_words = 0;
    size_t error = 0;
    if (!parser(foo, &words, &num_words, &error)) {
        if (errno == ENOMEM)
            fputs("Not enough memory. :(\n\n", stderr);
        else fprintf(stderr, "Error at position %zu: \"%s\"\n\n", error, foo + error);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    puts("List of words:");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_words; ++i) {
        printf("\"%s\"\n", words[i]);
        free(words[i]);
    }
    free(words);
}
```

C should be renamed brainf*ck ...

<sup>*) [Three Star Programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

1. you modify the value of `str` in the body of the function  (in the line `str = new;`  (don't use `new` as an identifier, more if you plan to use this code as C++ code, as `new` is a reserved word in C++).  As you don't call `malloc(3)` in the function body, it's quite normal you get a problem from `free(3)`, as free **requires** to be passed a pointer previously generated with malloc (and only once, so you cannot call it twice with the same pointer).  This is the reason of you getting `SIGABRT` and the like.  As a general rule, don't call `free(3)` in a function you don't also call malloc **for the same pointer**.  That use is error prone and you will run into trouble more than once a day if you insist in doing everything in a single function.
2. better than apologize for the messy form of the code, please, clean it before posting.  Post a minimu (meaning the minimum code that shows the error), full (meaning that we can compile it and observe the result you post as failing), verifiable (code that shows it producing the observed result, and not the expected one) and complete (this means we have nothing to do but compile it and run) code (so we can test it failing as you say, without having to correct it first)  That way, we can make a diagnostic of what happens in your code. If we need to correct the code just to make it runnable, we can correct the main problem you are observing and be unable to see the mistake.  You see? :)

## Note about using `new` as an identifier in C code:

Many Unit Testing frameworks require your code to be compilable as C++ code, so it can be used by the framework (at least Google Test requires this)   If you plan to write unit tests for your code, remember that `new` is a reserved word in C++ for the operator `new`, and so, your code will produce syntax errors if you try to compile it with a c++ compiler.  Better if you don't use it.